# Create img each x time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello I need a script that has an image that shows for 30 seconds after it disappears but after 5 minutes it appears again and disappears after 30 seconds and so continue

Can you help me please?

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".content2").fadeIn(1500);
    },3000);
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="content2" style="display:none;">IMAGE</div>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content2" style="display:none;">IMAGE</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var showImageFor30sAndHide = function()
        {
            $(".content2").fadeIn(1500).delay(30 * 1000).fadeOut(1500);
        };

        // Start a interval that call previous method every 5 minutes.

        setInterval(showImageFor30sAndHide, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval and setTimeout can be used together.

```js
hideInThirty();
setInterval(function() {
  $("div").show();
  hideInThirty();
}, 330000);

function hideInThirty() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").hide();
  }, 30000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>IMAGE</div>
```